# Core i7 performs very badly?

Tags: cpu, performance, intel-core-i7, intel-core-i5

I would like to know why a core i7 HQ 6700 2.6GHz performs very badly compared to a  core i5-4570 3.2GHz. This is the scenario, I'm running a very expensive method to populate a MSSQL DB, the i7 taks (+/-)30min while the i5 (+/-)30sec, I mean the gap  is gigantic, I cannot seem to understand why. Also The i7 runs 24Gb DDR4 while the i5 16Gb (probably ddr3). Both use SSDs which are in the same range of performance.

I cannot seem to understand what with this huge performance gap.

https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i7-6700HQ-vs-Intel-Core-i5-4570/m34954vs2770

Comment: Unless your code is multi-threaded and uses a substantial amount of memory the i5 should be faster than the i7.

Comment: You might have very differently configured databases or more difference that are not just hardware if the difference is really 30 seconds versus 30 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The i7 HQ is a mobile processor. The official [comparison](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/compare.html?productIds=75043,88967). Both are quad cores, the i7 has HT so it does have, according to your linked benchmark, higher performance on benchmarks that utilize more than 4 cores.

The optimization targets for the i7 are going to be different as it's a mobile CPU. The i5 does have an advantage in single core performance. In the end it depends on what you actually want to do.